# how to spawn items in map circle in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have written a script card to spawn coin item. However, it only spawns correctly if the map is square. I have a round map, but it seems to spawn the same as a square map, which really doesn't work, because it will cause the coins to spawn outside the map. Anyone with any ideas please help me

Comment: Have you tried [`Random.insideUnitCircle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitCircle.html) ? You can offset the coordinates with the center and height of your map.

Comment: i tried but it's not as expected

Answer (score 0):

This determines spawn point to be inside a cube limited by collider bounds:

```
Vector3 point = new Vector3(
            Random.Range(collider.bounds.min.x, collider.bounds.max.x),
            Random.Range(collider.bounds.min.y, collider.bounds.max.y),
            Random.Range(collider.bounds.min.z, collider.bounds.max.z)
            );
```

Just try spawning randomly inside a unit sphere with a given radius instead:

```
Vector3 point = Random.insideUnitSphere * radius;
```